# VLC like control panel in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, video, user-interface, vlc

I'm writting a video player application (using AVFoundation) for MacOS X and I would like to have the same kind of control panel than VLC (fading out after a few second).

What is the best option to implement this?

I'm thinking about a custom NSWindowControl object that I could design separately with the interface builder but I don't understand very well how to sequence the creation and display step, but I was wondering if there was a best option subclassing a NSViewController...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply add a NSPanel in the interface builder, add it as a child window from my main window and add a notification when the main window resize to resize the panel accordingly.